# Как сделать такой же код без eval'a?

Tags: javascript

Я делаю "генетический калькулятор", он должен "скрещивать" каждую букву каждого элемента `gens[[],[]]` с другой другого элемента.

Есть такой код, который создаёт код, который затем исполняется:

```
for (var u in gens) {
    var estr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < gens[u].length; i++) {
        var na = gens[u][i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        estr += 'for(var ' + na + '=0;' + na + '<=1;' + na + '++){\n';
    }

    estr += 'var res=cross([';
    for (var i = 0; i < gens[u].length; i++) {
        var na = gens[u][i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        estr += 'gens[' + u + '][' + i + '].charAt(' + na + '),';
    }

    estr = estr.substring(0, estr.length - 1);
    estr += ']);\nif(!test(gomets[' + u + '],res,true)){gomets[' + u + '].push(res);}\n';
    for (var i = 0; i < gens[u].length; i++) {
        estr += '}\n';
    }

    alert(estr);
    //eval(estr);
}
```

Суть в том, что он при `gens=[['AA','Bb'],['aa','BB']];` создаёт сначала код:

```
for (var A = 0; A <= 1; A++) {
    for (var B = 0; B <= 1; B++) {
        var res = cross([gens[0][0].charAt(A), gens[0][1].charAt(B)]);
        if (!test(gomets[0], res, true)) {
            gomets[0].push(res);
        }
    }
}
```

А потом

```
for (var A = 0; A <= 1; A++) {
    for (var B = 0; B <= 1; B++) {
        var res = cross([gens[1][0].charAt(A), gens[1][1].charAt(B)]);
        if (!test(gomets[1], res, true)) {
            gomets[1].push(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Суть в том, чтобы код создавал столько вложенных циклов, сколько элементов в `gens[u]`, например, `gens[0]`.

Каждый цикл должен считать от 0 до 1 (так длина строки "AA" ,"bb" и тд 2 символа) и записывать результат в переменную, имя которой соответствует `gens[u].[номер элемента/цикла].charAt(0);` в теле самого вложенного цикла исполняется функция, ей в параметры должен попадать масив с элементами `gens[u][0].charAt(имя счётчика цикла)`, тк индекс колеблется от 0 до 1, то цикл берёт каждую букву. Я думал над алгоритмом, ничего лучше придумать не смог, т.к количество элементов в `gens[u]` колеблется и все буквы всех элементов надо по очереди передавать функции, а для этого нужно столько циклов, сколько элементов в `gens[u]`.

Собственно вопрос: можно ли это организовать без `eval'a`?

**ps** Если что не понятно в вопросе, спрашивайте, я объясню.

**UPD:**
для `gens=[['AA','Bb','Cc'],['aa','BB','Cc']];` генерируется код:

```
for (var A = 0; A <= 1; A++) {
    for (var B = 0; B <= 1; B++) {
        for (var C = 0; C <= 1; C++) {
            var res = cross([gens[0][0].charAt(A), gens[0][1].charAt(B), gens[0][2].charAt(C)]);
            if (!test(gomets[0], res, true)) {
                gomets[0].push(res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: на 95% уверен, что можно

Comment: я думая над этим уже 3 дня но (может потому что я учусь в школе и самоучка) никак не могу придумать такой код для языков без eval'a например  pascal (конечно он ушёл в прошлое Имхо) т.е для кампилятором а не для интерпритаторов

Comment: может я не совсем правильно понял вопрос, но попробуйте обратить свой взор в сторону рекурсии

Comment: Пожалуйста обьясните поподробнее я недопонимаю что такое рекурсия это когда чтото само на себя ссылается? Если неправильно знаю nермины не ругайтесь а лучше обьясните новичку :)

Comment: Чтобы понять рекурсию, нужно сначала понять рекурсию, а для этого нужно сначала понять рекурсию, а для этого нужно сначала понять рекурсию...

Если вы все же поняли рекурсию, значит вы поняли рекурсию, а значит вы поняли рекурсию, а значит вы поняли рекурсию...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Без рекурсии и излишних вложенных циклов.

Тут получается для каждого массива двоичная система. Соответственно комбинаций разных генов может быть 2^(длина массива). Надо перебрать все различные комбинации...

```
var gens = [['AA', 'Bb', 'Cc'], ['aa', 'BB', 'Cc']];

for (u in gens) {
    var gen = gens[u];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1 << gen.length; i++) {// 2^длина массива комбинаций
        var args = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < gen.length; j++) {// создаем массив разных сочетаний
            var gi = (i & (1 << j)) >> j;// получаем индекс буквы 
                                         // по номеру комбинации
                                         // и по номеру индекса элемента массива
                                         // (сорри в генетике не силен, 
                                         // что как называется не в курсе)
            args.push(gen[j].charAt(gi));// заполняем массив параметров для cross
        }
        var res = cross(args);
        if (!test(gomets[u], res, true)) {
            gomets[u].push(res);
        }
    }
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/LHBS4/) тест для составления списка аргументов.

Comment: Спасибо громадное а то я думал что реализовать такое без eval'a нереально (пока опыта мало:) можно было бы дважды плюсовать ответ этот плюсовал бы дважы!

Comment: Да реально работает только ещё два вопроса к гуру please можете сделать так чтобы все гены из gens[0] скрещивались и записывались в gomets[0] а все гены из gens[1] скрещивались и записывались в gomets[1] ато у вас ВСЕ гены и из gens скрещиваются и записываются в gomets[0] 

И ещё один вопрос что за операторы & >> <<  кагда слышал гдето что это побитовые операторы но даже понятия не имею как их использовать и не могу про них ничего найти где вы научились использовать их (операторы & >> <<)?

Comment: Поправил.

``<<`` и ``>>`` - операторы сдвига. Сдвигают разряды числа в двоичной чистеме в соответствующую сторону. & - побитовое "и", сравнение если бит есть в обоих операндах, он остается, если хотя бы в одном из операндов бит нулевой, будет ноль (ну как обычное "и" - && - только побитово).
например:

    10101 << 3 == 10101000;// эквивалентно умножению на 2^3
    10101 >> 3 == 10; //деление без остатка на 2^3
    10101 & 100 == 100; // 3-й бит есть у обоих

Откуда я про них знаю уже не помню :)

Comment: Спасибо громаднишее!!!

Comment: А где вы учились программировать?

Comment: да как и многие, синклер, школа, институт... потом уже мозги выстроенные, решения строятся сами собой, на основе опыта. но до "гуру" все равно далеко :)

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var u in gens){
    var tmp;
    var this_pair=gens[u];
    for (var i=0; i<=this_pair.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<=this_pair.length; j++){
            tmp=cross([this_pair[0].charAt[i],this_pair[1].charAt[j]]);
            if(!test(gomets[u], tmp, true)){
                gomets[u].push(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

не тестировалось

Comment: Ток эт... не надо так часто length считать...

Comment: > Ток эт... не надо так часто length считать...

А то что, шестеренки перетрутся? :)

PS К слову, length не считается каждый раз, это всего лишь свойство соответствующего массива.

Comment: Я взял парные элементы, не учел другие варианты. Надо переписать и добавить еще один цикл.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov какой-то странный бенчмарк. На одной и той же машине Chrome у меня выдал 27,335 op/sec, а FireFox всего 3,287 в 8 раз медленнее- это не нормально. Мне кажется, что тест какой-то не такой.

Comment: @ReinRaus, такая разница из-за `console.log()`, я думаю. Можете любой другой использовать, там их полно: [aku loop length](http://jsperf.com/aku-loop-length), [.length comparison](http://jsperf.com/length-comparison), [for loop length cache](http://jsperf.com/for-loop-length-cache)

Или свой написать.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, это скорее всего опять же из-за `console.log()`. Изначально консоль пустая и проходит тест thing.length, а тест thing_len проходит с забитой консолью.  
Добавил в тот тест [Revision 2][1] и теперь результаты стали совсем другие. Не разобрался как делать `console.clear()` между тестами- так результаты были бы адекватнее.
[1]:http://jsperf.com/length-vs-var-setting/2

Comment: @ReinRaus - да нет, нормальный там тест, у меня в chromium'e вариант с arr.length медленее примерно на 25-30%, я просто перепутал результаты...

Я знаю что arr.length не пересчитывает длину массива, лишь пытался указать на то, что за этим свойством идет очень много обращений и логичнее, красивее (да и быстрее) было бы вынести это значение в локальную переменную. вот после:

    var this_pair=gens[u];
    var length = this_pair.length;
    // ну и дальше
    for (var i=0; i<=length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<=length; j++){
            // ....
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

Да, действительно нужна рекурсия. Будет, что-то в этом родe:

```
var genetic = function(gen, gomet, args) {
    // вытаскиваем пару из стека
    var pairs = gen.shift();

    for (var pair in pairs) {
        // аналог for (var X = 0; X <= 1; X++)
        for (var x in pairs[pair]) {
            // аргумент для cross
            new_args = args.concat(pairs[pair][x]);

            // если еще остались пары в стеке
            if (gen.length) { 
                // то вызываем рекурсивно
                genetic(gen.slice(), gomet, new_args);

            // иначе выполняем основной алгоритм
            } else {

                var res = cross(new_args);
                if (!test(gomet, res, true)) {
                    gomet.push(res);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (var pos in gens) {
    var gen = gens[pos];
    var gomet = gomets[pos];

    // slice(), потому что понадобится копия
    genetic(gen.slice(), gomet, []);
}
```

Comment: Получилось тоже же самое, что и у @Ёхарный Бабай :)

Comment: Проблема в том что все элементы gens  должны добавлятся в функцию cross (посмотрите UPD вопроса!)

Comment: @Rules, действительно, не внимательно прочитал. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсия. Грубо говоря когда функция вызывает сама себя:

```
function foo(some_var){
alert(some_var);
if(some_var<=0)return;
else foo(--some_var);
}

foo(10);
```

Comment: Ладно смирюсь с этим, наверно без eval'a смогу сделать код только после окончания института :)

Comment: @Rules, Что же вы сдаетесь-то? Растревожили тут воспаленные умы и теперь говорите не надо?

Comment: Да я умы не останавливаю пусть думают а сам успокоюсь пока и обойдусь Eval'ом Если умы подкинут решение воспользуюсь

Answer (score 0):

Может вот так? (Нуждается в проверке)

```
for (var u in gens) {
    var f = [];
    f.push(function(resarr) {
        var res = cross(resarr.reverse());
        if(!test(gomets[u], res, true)) {
            gomets[u].push(res);
        }
    });
    for(var i = gens[u].length; i-- > 0;) {
        var f1 = function() {
            var i1 = i;
            var l = f.length - 1;
            return function(resarr) {
                for(var a=0; a<2; a++) {
                    resarr.push(gens[u][i1].charAt(a));
                    f[l](resarr);
                    resarr.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        var f2 = f1();
        f.push(f2);
    }
    f[f.length-1]([]);
}
```

Хотя. Если учесть, что все эти for(var A, for(var B -- циклы от 0 до 1, то можно сделать общий цикл (в этом случае от 0 до 3) и разбить на биты операциями / и %
И тогда вложенные циклы не нужны и вся эта трахомудрия тоже